# scale from 10 ft. by 10 ft. to reasonable working size in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I used to design rugs by hand on paper;  now Im trying to design a 10 ft.  by 10ft. area rug in illustrator but do not know how to get the proper scaled down proportion to use

Comment: Why scale? Why not just create a 10x10ft artboard?

Comment: is there a target warp count or knot density? This strikes me as a situation where aliasing from scaling up is a feature not a bug.

Comment: Hi Julie, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thank you for that info.  I am using a grid to help with this so Ill make my grid a 1" grid

Answer (score 1):

For that size, I'd be working 1:1 - I have created many exhibition stands, bull-up banners etc at similar sizes.

Just create a 10x10ft Artboard, and get creative :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a ratio. A 10"x10" document means every 1" is 1'. A 20"x20" document means every 1" is 6" at scale.

Comment: Why do at scale at all? Illustrator is perfectly capable of using that size.

Comment: I wouldnt bother scaling, personally. Just figured I'd answer the question anyway